# Ajax result from PHP to be clickable and run a Jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I've been learning PHP over the past year or so and recently been playing with Ajax and Jquery.  The reason for this is that it seems inefficient to constantly fire PHP scripts off and reload my html each time I want to display or do something.
So what I'm doing:  I have a html document with input fields which I need to populate with data.  The data is retrieved via a Ajax post call to a PHP script and returns a Json_encoded string.  Jquery uses the JSON object to iterate through.
Where I am:  I have managed to have Ajax pull back the correct results and populate the input elements I require.  The results should be displayed as dynamically named Div IDs as list elements for each.  This kind of works but I'm probably over complicating the process.

What I have with this code:  So the results come back, and as I start typing in the search box, multiple results will return in the fashion I like.  The on(click...) event works to a degree - i.e. it does populate the fields BUT only the last returned result from the Ajax call (last item).

I think the code is almost there (although could be made less complex but it's out of my reach at my current level).  It's probably my flow which is wrong (i.e. using .each and then using a click event within it ...) ... I've attempted multiple ways of re-arranging the code but cannot fathom it.  Any advice would be amazing.  Full code relating to this is attached.

HTML:`

```
<input type="text" id="search_js" autocomplete="off">
<!-- Show Results -->

<h4 id="results-text">  <b id="search-string"></b>  </h4>
    <div id="resultsdiv">
        <ul id="results">
            <!--Results should show up here with custom Div IDs to keep unique -->
        </ul>
    <!-- END resultsdiv -->
    </div>
    <!-- End search-container div -->
</div>
...`
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP

$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = "$search_string%";

if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
// Build Query
$searchstmt = "select * from vw_person_full where name like :s;";
$database->query($searchstmt);

$database->bind(':s', $search_string);

//Custom PDO function - returns associative array
$result_array = $database->resultset();

$output = $result_array;

//convert result array into json format
$json_result = json_encode($output);
echo $json_result;
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("input#search_js").on("keyup", function(e) {

// Set Timeout
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
// Set Search String
var search_string = $(this).val();
// Do Search
if(search_string == '') {
  $("ul#results").fadeOut();
  $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();

} else {
  $("ul#results").fadeIn();
  $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
  $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
};

  });

var newsearchres;

function search() {

var query_value = $('input#search_js').val();
var output = '';
//if search box is not empty  :
if(query_value !== '') {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: {
      query: query_value
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(searchres) {



      $.each(searchres, function(i, val) {
        var countval = i;
        //searchres = JSON.parse(searchres);

        newsearchres = searchres[i];

        console.log(val+"   " + countval);
        //individual divs for results with ID=divres_##
        //output += '<div data-val-index="countval"id="divres' + countval + '" class="cl_divres">';
         output += '<div data-val-index="'+countval+'" id="divres' + countval + '" class="cl_divres">';
        output += '<li>' + val.fighter_name + '</li>';
        //end individual divs:
        output += '</div>';
        //End search result Div:
        output += '</div>';

        //Display output in the result div:
        $('#resultsdiv').html(output);
        console.log(searchres);

      });


      }

    });

  };

}


function showDetail(ref) {
        var val_id = $(ref).attr('data-val-index');

        var val = $.each(newsearchres, function(i, val2) {

          if(i == val_id) return val2;

        });

        $("#pid").prop({
          "value": val.pid
        });
        $("#firstname").prop({
          "value": val.first_name
        });
        $("#lastname").prop({
          "value": val.last_name
        });
        $("#fightername").prop({
          "value": val.fighter_name
        });
        $("#addressl1").prop({
          "value": val.address_line1
        });
        $("#addressl2").prop({
          "value": val.address_line2
        });
        $("#town").prop({
          "value": val.town
        });
        $("#city").prop({
          "value": val.city
        });
        $("#county").prop({
          "value": val.county
        });
        $("#postcode").prop({
          "value": val.postcode
        });
        $("#dob").prop({
          "value": val.dob
        });
        $("#nat").prop({
          "value": val.nationality
        });
        $("#email").prop({
          "value": val.email
        });
        $("#homephone").prop({
          "value": val.home_phone
        });
        $("#mobilephone").prop({
          "value": val.mobile_phone
        });


      };

//  $(document).find("div[id^='divres_']").on('click', function() {
$(document).on('click', 'div[id^="divres"]', function() {

    console.log(this);
    console.log("clicked");
        showDetail(this);

    });

});
```

Really sorry for crappy image - but hopefully it makes sense.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: you are appending the html in result div and playing with id , within iteration .. may be that s creating issues.

Comment: can you better describe what exactly is happening? all items are displayed but the onclick event only works on the last item? maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: no its not required .. now caught yout problem.. let me find a solution

Comment: Attach event after each. Now you attach event to every existed div. 
Or use 'divres_' + countval as id.
And also you overwrite $('#resultsdiv') content on every iteration, is it ok?

Comment: now you are missing to iterate again since the first $.each is to get the index of responsed object

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind right now is that you are ending the search result div at each item. I am only inclined to this because I see you open a new div in the $.each but you close 2.

See below:

```
$.each(searchres, function (i, val) {

                var countval = i;

                //individual divs for results with ID=divres_##
                output += '<div id="divres_' + countval + '" class="cl_divres">';
                output += '<li>' + val.name + '</li>';
                //end individual divs:
                output += '</div>';
                //End search result Div:
                output += '</div>'; // <--- add this after the $.each?
```

Comment: ahh, thanks for that George - good spot :) - removed it though and it didn't resolve the issue, but the DOM looks better.

Comment: on another note, you mentioned above that I need to better describe the issue. What it does currently is return my results from the PHP script (this is a MySQL lookup which just returns all the relevant roles based on the posted Ajax value (in my case this is a name) - the search has a wildcard to produce a "live search" style result under my search box.  I have this part working, the bit that doesn't work is the "click and populate" ..it does populate, but only the last row returned in my Json result - which is fine on one returned result but not on many.  Hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: can you give me a live link for the above? I want to see the actual phenomenon. May this be because of the $.prop()? The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set.

Comment: Thanks for replying George - I'd love to give the link but it's behind some security due to having live data - best I can do is use jsfiddle ... although I don't know how to incorporate the test json data into it (it's included but not functioning).  link is : https://jsfiddle.net/nra5hyar/

Comment: You need to bring the json object in javascript and then update the search function so that it searches from the json. I started to modify the code but it seems to be more of an overkill :) Add some screenshots best so I can quickly get a feel of what exactly is needed. ps: https://jsfiddle.net/nra5hyar/9/

Comment: apologies for the rubbish msPaint screenshot - hope it shines a little more light onto the requirement.

Comment: No problem, it helped. But based on what you're trying to achieve, I would recommend changing the methodology a bit. Use an ajax request to only retrieve the names, thus minimizing traffic and resources being used. Then, use another ajax request to retrieve all of the needed information once the user clicks on a suggestion and populate the fields. This way, you only load all of the data for only one selected item. I am thinking of this purely to keep it scalable, but this also provides a more modular approach and it's easier to detect and correct issues.

Comment: ahh I didn't think of that - still new to Ajax and Jquery - My thoughts were that I populate everything in one call and then just reference the entire data set - 2 Ajax requests seem completely obvious now ... will have to get my thinking hat on though on how to logically do it.  Got to go spend time with the kids now though so will probably be tomorrow when I get an update - but will definitely update with my progress - thanks all for the input so far.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that "You are accessing the val for each li events that is accesing outside the each iteration so getting the last values only ."

So try to get the values from index .something as below -

```
 $.each(searchres, function (i, val) {
                       var countval = i;

                    //individual divs for results with ID=divres_##
                    output += '<div data-val-index="countval" 
                    id="divres_' + countval + '" class="cl_divres">';
                        output += '<li>' + val.name + '</li>';
                        //end individual divs:
                        output += '</div>';
                        //End search result Div:
                        output += '</div>';

    //Display output in the result div:
                        $('#resultsdiv').html(output);



$(document).find("div[id^='divres_']").on('click',function(){showDetail(this); }); 
                    });
```

Now your callback for event may be as -

```
function showDetail(ref)
{
var val_id=$(ref).attr('data-val-index');
var val=$.each(searchres, function (i, val2) { if(i==val_id) return val2 ;});

                        $("#pid").prop({"value": val.pid});
                        $("#firstname").prop({"value": val.first_name});
                        $("#lastname").prop({"value": val.last_name});
                        $("#fightername").prop({"value": val.name});
                        $("#addressl1").prop({"value": val.address_line1});
                        $("#addressl2").prop({"value": val.address_line2});
                        $("#town").prop({"value": val.town});
                        $("#city").prop({"value": val.city});
                        $("#county").prop({"value": val.county});
                        $("#postcode").prop({"value": val.postcode});
                        $("#dob").prop({"value": val.dob});
                        $("#nat").prop({"value": val.nationality});
                        $("#email").prop({"value": val.email});
                        $("#homephone").prop({"value": val.home_phone});
                        $("#mobilephone").prop({"value": val.mobile_phone});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Rohit, appreciate your time and advice in response.  I altered my JS script to include your suggestion above but it isn't working for me.  Not sure i have the layout 100% correct but the "showDetail" function is part of my original "Search" function and the .each is at the start of the "showDetail" function ... and the "$.each(searchres, function (i, val)" suggestion you made replaced my original loop.

Comment: Thanks again Rohit - the error is : Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined (line 86) : var countval = i;  I believe this is due to the variable not being available to this new variable outside the .each loop ... I wish I had the knowledge on how to reference this so I apologies in advance.  It's more than likely due to how I've used your code, so again i apologies.  I'll update the original question above with how my script looks at the moment.

Comment: as per your old scripts , the modified answer might works well .. check it

Comment: ok, getting there I think - it now displays correctly the results in the console (using console.log (val.name); so it is returning the Json.  It also displays the returned results in the dynamic named Divs.   The on(click...) doesn't seem to work however - no errors in console, it just doesn't seem to call it.  Will update my question with the current script so you can see where I put everything you gave me.

Comment: define showDetail function outside of the function definition of seacrh()

Comment: apologies for the late reply on this.  I moved the showDetail function out and the divs populate still with the correct values, but on(click) isn;t firing the function - stuck a console.log("clicked!"); in there as well and that doesn't show ... so it's like the on click function doesn't work.  Also noticed that since I moved the function out of Search, these lines cannot reference "searchres" ... not sure how to resolved that: function showDetail(ref) {
            var val_id = $(ref).attr('data-val-index');
            var val = $.each(searchres, function(i, val2) {

Comment: sods law - figured out the "on click" and now it is registering.  The only error I see now is this (which is related to searchres not being defined in showDetail:     ReferenceError: searchres is not defined
 

var val = $.each(searchres, function(i, val2) {

Comment: "searchres" Just declare it at top of script and it will be available for all functions.

Comment: ok - so I've declared the searchres variable (i've called it newsearchres) outside the functions - and in the Search function I'm setting the newsearchres =searchres ... if I do that, I end up with populated fields but last item in the array (due to the .each loop where I define the variable equal to) - if I set newsearchres=searchres[0] it only populates the first item ... I've updated my code above to show you what it looks like now .... almost certain it's a small thing now to resolve I just cannot see it!

Comment: do newsearchres = searchres; before the $.each , hope , you will get the result

Comment: bringing the variable out of the loop has stopped the fields from populating - no error, they just don't get populated with any data